# Unable to bind Super key on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard, 17.10, shortcuts

I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 and when I pressed the Super key nothing happened. So I went into keyboard shortcuts and tried to map it to an action, but it wasn't registering.

To be more specific - when I'm on the "Set shortcut" window and press the Super key, nothing happens. I expect it to register as the keybind for the selected action.

Also Super registers properly when used with another key, for example Super + A

Comment: Super should open Activities. If you click on Activities at the top left, does it appear?

Comment: Yes, it appears, however it doesn't if I press the Super key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem using Gnome Tweaks:

1. Install Gnome Tweaks from Ubuntu Software
2. Launch `Tweaks`
3. Select `Keyboard & Mouse`
4. For `Overview Shortcut` select `Right Super` (instead of `Left Super`)